# Two bridged interfaces with multiple IPs, NAT required, iptables

Tags: iptables, nat, bridge

I try to setup a weird configuration on a debian based box.

This is kind of industrial PC with two network interfaces eth0 and eth1. I'm using this as a 'scanning device' for use in customers networks. Some of them use DHCP, some not. Some can give me a fixed IP, some cant and dont even know the DHCP address my device would receive.

So I created the following setup in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

# Bridge interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
      bridge_ports eth0 eth1
      bridge_hw aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff

# pre-set interface IP for client requirements, if DHCP is not working
auto br0:1
iface br0:1 inet static
    address 172.16.21.150
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.16.21.0
    broadcast 172.16.21.255
    # Gateway
    post-up route add default gw 172.16.21.254
    pre-down route del default gw 172.16.21.254


# Set default fallback interface IP address
auto br0:100
iface br0:100 inet static
    address 169.254.111.111
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 169.254.111.0
    broadcast 169.254.111.255
```

As you see, there are three interfaces. br0 is used for DHCP, br0:1 for static IP given by the customer. Usually br0 and br0:1 will not be in used at the same time.
And br0:100 is also static, but with link local address. This is used by me to access the box without attached computer monitor, simply via IP and ssh.
That all works like a charm except when I connect my laptop via direct connetion to br0:100 (remember, its kind of virtual not a dedicated pysical interface!).

When working via ssh on the box, I am able to access the customer's network and also connect to the internet (besides possible fw rules at customer's end...)

But I cannot access Internet from my laptop but only the cusomer's network.
So my idea was that local customers configuration does allow only Internet access from their network range. But my laptop has other range. The glorious idea was to setup NAT and I tried these simple NAT rules:

```
# IP Forwarding im Kernel aktivieren
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Masqerading auf br0 und br0.1 aktivieren
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0:1 -j MASQUERADE

# Forwarding Regeln einrichten
# Forwarding etablierter Verbindungen von extern (br0 & br0.1) nach intern (br0.100)
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0:100 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0:1 -o br0:100 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Forwarding aller Verbindungen von intern (br0.100) nach extern (br0 & br0.1)
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0:100 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0:100 -o br0:1 -j ACCEPT
```

This breaks my whole setup. The box itself cannot connect to the network anymore.

I have no clue whats wrong and how can I fix that. Any ideas are appreciated.

Regards
Olaf

Answer (score 0):

1. You use aliases, not virtual interfaces. An alias is just an ip address on interface. So you cannot use it in `--input-interface` (`-i`) and in `output-interface` (`-o`) options of iptables rules.
2. Check the whole firewall rule set with command `iptables-save -c`. Likely you will see zero counters of your rules where you specify aliases (with colon in an interface name).
3. If I've understood you correctly, you need following steps to achieve what you want:

   - On your laptop assign an ip address from range `169.254.111.0/24` (for example, `169.254.111.112/24`) and default gateway `169.254.111.111`.
   - On the linux box you need iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --src 169.254.111.112 -j ACCEPT
```

4. Also better disable sending of redirects on the linux box:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

5. To troubleshoot issues run the `tcpdump`.